# Array to string conversion error - Angular and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angular, laravel, database

I'm submitting a contact form using Angular and Laravel. In the form, there is some checkboxes. User can select multiple options (services) and the request will go to Laravel controller through API. In console.log, the request is working fine but when I'm trying to access services in Laravel, I'm getting this error in console:

> Error: "Array to string conversion"

Angular Component:

```
export class ContactComponent {
  contactForm!: FormGroup;
  successMsg: boolean = false;
  warningMsg: boolean = false;
  public isSaving = false;
  Data: Array<any> = [
    {name: 'floor', value: 'Floor Maintenance'},
    {name: 'deep', value: 'Deep Cleaning'},
    {name: 'residential', value: 'Residential Cleaning'},
    {name: 'commercial', value: 'Commercial Cleaning'},
    {name: 'industrial', value: 'Industrial Cleaning'},
    {name: 'sanitization', value: 'Sanitization and Disinfection'}
  ];
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      message: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      
      services: this.fb.array([], [Validators.required]),
    })
  }

onCheckboxChange(e: any) {
    const services: FormArray = this.contactForm.get('services') as FormArray;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      services.push(new FormControl(e.target.value));
    } else {
      let i: number = 0;
      services.controls.forEach((item: any) => {
        if (item.value == e.target.value) {
          services.removeAt(i);
          return;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
  }

onSubmit() {
    this.isSaving = true;
    this._emailService.contact(this.contactForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log('Success!', response);
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Error.', error);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Laravel Controller

```
public function submit(Request $request) {
        Mail::to($request->email)->send(new Quotation($request));
        return response()->json($request->all, 200);
    }
```

Quotation.php

```
public function build(Request $request)
{
 return $this->markdown('emails.angular')->with([
 'name' => $request->name,
 'email' => $request->email,
 'phone' =>  $request->phone,
 'message'   => $request->message,
 'services'  =>  $request->services
 ]);
}
```

email.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
# A New Quotation Received
 
@component('mail::table')

| Details:       |               |                |
| :------------- |:-------------:| --------------:|
| Email          |               | {{ $email }}   |
| Name           |               | {{ $name }}    |
| Phone          |               | {{ $phone }}   |
| Message        |               | {{ $message }} |
| Services       |               | {{ $services}} |

@endcomponent
```

It only happens when I try to send the email. If I access services in Controller like this `return response()->json($request->services)`, I get this response in console.

> ['Floor Maintenance', 'Deep Cleaning']

But unable to send the email